# esale_spree module

Tags: spree

I want to use the esale_spree module which is used as a connector for ecommerce web site and openERP, I have downloaded it from the following link:

**http://apps.openerp.com/addon/2431?filter={%22version%22%3A+3%2C+%22order_by%22%3A+%22last_update+desc%2C+click_counter+desc%22%2C+%22author%22%3A+142}&page=0**

I have installed the module and linked it with the spree site using the api key.But I am not able to retrieve products,categories,orders,taxes etc  from spree. But when I insert some data in the esale_spree module's database then those values are visible through OpenERP esale_module. For example values in the **esale_spree_product** can be retrieved through openerp. But this isn't the way the connector should work, I guess.

Tell me the right way to use the connector.

tried with
spree - 1.0.0
rails - 1.9.2 , 1.9.3
Oerp version - 6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

That extension was Tested with spree 0.9.99 edge, which is more than 2 years old. It's likely that the api has been changed radically between 0.9 and 1.0, and it's been changed again between spree 1.0 and 1.1.